# Real-World, Operationalized Applications of Multi-Arm Bandits

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

Multi-armed bandits are wonderful and have lots of potential applications. However, I don't know many companies or real-world practitioners who have implemented bandit algorithms.

- **What are some examples of multi-bandits that are up and running?** By this I mean: An organization (company, government or whatever) has implemented the bandit. And the algorithm is live, performing explore/exploit and touching real-world decisions that change something (large or small). In the real world.
- **Refute this claim**: "Bandits are an academic novelty. Despite attractive theoretical properties, practitioners have systematically refused to adopt them in practice since their invention in 1952."

Note: I'm not asking for *potentially good (new) uses for bandits*. [There's already a question about that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230523/in-what-kind-of-real-life-situations-can-we-use-a-multi-arm-bandit-algorithm), and I agree there are lots of potential applications. I'm asking what anyone actually has used them to do. Lets list the biggest and most impressive applications!

Comment: This [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10040) looks like an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

Multi-armed bandits are commonly used. They were [used in Google Analytics](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2013/01/multi-armed-bandit-experiments.html) and until recently the linked post was a [part of the official documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160629020545/https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2844870?hl=en), but they probably switched to something else in the meantime. [Washington Post used them](https://web.archive.org/web/20161013134841/https://developer.washingtonpost.com/pb/blog/post/2016/02/08/bandito-a-multi-armed-bandit-tool-for-content-testing/) for automated experiments on content placement. Here you can find a [presentation by Netflix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY-BCNHd_dM) on how they use them for recommendations. [Polish Onet.pl site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Loe3D37UHlI) engineers used it for content recommendations. They are [used by Stich Fix](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2020/08/05/bandits/) fashion e-commerce. Notice that most of those resources are few years old, so not much of a novelty. If you google the phrase, you would easily find many more examples.

Comment: Is this the best we have? I find it underwhelming. The Google Analytics link seems out of date. The Washington Post article (and others) sounds like a science fair report instead of a mission-critical business application. They also seem like very low stakes. The Netflix application also seems like a science fair project, although somewhat more legit. How much revenue does this really affect?

Comment: You asked for "some examples", so I gave you some examples. You can easily find many others, also from other industries.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that Amazon uses bandit algorithms for the learning-to-rank problem and its specific applications to NLU. It is old but maybe it seems interesting.

https://www.amazon.science/blog/a-general-approach-to-solving-bandit-problems